# Can not debug the Xamarin Forms Android application in emulator Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've created a new blank Xamarin application using the Mobile Xamarin template (Xamarin version 5.0.0.2012).
I've made no changes after the project creation.
I can build the application and deploy it to the emulator and I can even start it and it works fine.
However when I click to Debug then Visual Studio only performs deploy and does not start the debugger.
When I select the VS Output Window and switch to Xamarin output I see the following error:

Project is not debuggable.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Yes. The project is in Debug mode.

Comment: Right click on solution-> options -> configurations   and check you have debug configuration. If it is not there then please add. Mentioned navigation is for VS mac. should be similar option will be there for VS 2019. if configuration is fine. then not sure what is the problem. Some time deleting bin and obj manually and restarting VS may solve this issue.

Comment: Debug configuration is there and I've tried everything. Nothing seems to help.

Comment: Not only check the solution configuration. If i set the Debug for solution configuration and set the Release for Android configuration, it coule be able to reproduce this issue. Please check the Build> Configuration Manager> Configurations for all the platforms.

Comment: I do not see 'Configurations for all the platforms' option. The both projects (Forms and Android) are set as debug and they are both set to Build. Androd also has 'Deploy' checked.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. The problem is the solution file (see my answer). I have created a separate solution for the Xamarin project and debugging works correctly there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been that the solution file (.sln) contained multiple various configurations for the two projects. This is probably caused by having an UWP project in the solution.
For example for my Forms project here are the .sln configuration lines that were created when I created the new android project within my existing solution:

```
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|.NET.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|.NET.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|ARM.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|ARM.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|ARM64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|ARM64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|x86.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|x86.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|.NET.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|.NET.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|ARM.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|ARM.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|ARM64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|ARM64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Mixed Platforms.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Mixed Platforms.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|x86.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|x86.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Here are the configuration lines when I create a project in the blank solution:

```
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {1568849E-FAE8-4B99-828C-AB2F683E1437}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Sadly I was unable to make it work. If I have UWP project in my solution then I get multiple configurations and I can not debug the Xamarin Android project. If I remove extra configurations required for the UWP project then the UWP project does not compile.
For now the solution is to have 2 separate .sln files. One for UWP project and one for Xamarin project.